# puppet cert list -all: Error: header too long

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I tried restarting my puppet master but the error still persists.

Also see it from all the puppet agents that try to join.

```
puppet agent --server puppet.example.com --waitforcert 60 --test --verbose
Error: Could not request certificate: Error 400 on SERVER: header too long
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There were empty ca request files on the puppet master server that needed to be removed.

here: /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/requests

Comment: Additional hint: Check with `df`, that your `/var` partition is not full.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the issue, remove the 0-byte file(s) and run the puppet command again.
`root@server:/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca# du *
0       ca_crl.pem
root@server:/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca# rm ca_crl.pem
root@server:/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca# puppet  cert -al`